# Alignment between fields in struct when crossing the boundary between parent / derived class

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

I'm trying to get more information about the behavior of the compiler when it aligns fields in a struct at the boundary between the parent struct and the child struct.

In the example below, the `struct_hasa` is what I had always assumed was going on under the covers in the compiler when defining something like `struct_isa` (which is a simple base class and derived class), but when I run this test on gcc/clang, I get different memory layouts between the has-a and is-a structs.  Conversely, msvc has the same layout between is-a and has-a.

Summary: gcc aligns the first field of the child struct right after the last field of the parent struct, as if the fields of the parent struct were part of the child struct, instead of a separate entity that has an alignment/packing determined by the fields in that struct.

A secondary question relates to the `struct0` struct.  If I don't include it, then gcc/clang changes behavior and the layout for is-a and has-a are identical.  I'm not sure what feature/flag that its presence is toggling in the compiler that changes the observed behavior.

If anyone has any keywords or c++ feature names that address this topic, I would be grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
struct struct0 {
};
 
struct struct1 : struct0 {
    long x;
    char f2;
};
 
struct struct_isa : struct1 {
    char f3;
};
 
struct struct_hasa {
    struct1 s1;
    char f3;
};
 
 
struct_isa isa;
struct_hasa hasa;
 
 
int main() {
    int isa_padding = (char*)&isa.f3 - (char*)&isa.f2;
    int hasa_padding = (char*)&hasa.f3 - (char*)&hasa.s1.f2;
 
    printf("isa padding: %d, hasa padding: %d\n", isa_padding, hasa_padding);
    // linux gcc/clang: isa padding: 1, hasa padding: 8
    // msvc: isa padding: 4, hasa padding: 4 (==4 because different sizes of long, but not important when comparing between isa and hasa on same platform)
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, `long` is 32 bits on MSVC but 64 bits in gcc (assuming 64 bit builds), so that's definitely going to throw things off.

Comment: @PaulSanders - yeah, I'll tweak the output to show that the size difference isn't important, but the difference between the 2 layouts

Comment: `long long` should do it.  That's 64 bits on both.

Comment: Padding is inplementation-specific. Why do you need to know about it? One difference between including and not including struct0 is that without it struct1 becomes a C-compatible struct and must abide by both C and C++ rules.

Comment: I'm doing some RE on binaries, and knowing what situations trigger this change in behavior will let me make my tool operate better.

Comment: Padding is *not* required.  Most modern processors can access values that are not aligned; it just slows things down.  So, instead of using one memory fetch, the processor may need to make multiple fetches, then adjust values in the register.  Alignment is an efficiency issue.

Comment: There is a document called [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) which gcc follows. It describes every aspect of layout. MSVC on the other hand... who knows, I don't see it documented, but llvm-cl can emulate it, so it must be known somehow.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit your pointer to the Itanium abi is probably the answer.  I had seen mention of it before, but due to the name I skipped it thinking it was specific to that processor.

Comment: @n.m [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-170#x64-type-and-storage-layout) seems to cover it